# How to create a transparent overlay on a camera view with a clear section in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, camera, mask

I am trying to create a camera view which shows a transparent layer and a clear section in between for the user to focus on a particular section.

For example sake I have created a view controller which has a sub view with red color. Added another transparent layer on view controller view.

[image]

I created a simple view which will be added as a mask view on top of this to get that clear red view in the middle of screen.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var redView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var transparentView: UIView!

    let maskView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        self.maskView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width - 30, height: 160)
        self.maskView.center = self.view.center
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.maskView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.transparentView.mask = self.maskView
    }


}
```

But this is what I end up with

[image]

EDIT: 
I want exactly the opposite of this, with 50% opaque whitish layer covering red view completely except for a rectangular clear section which shows the red view beneath the 50% opaque layer.

How can I do this ?
Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Its very unclear what you're asking.  Are you sure you don't mean "opaque" instead of transparent?

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup Transparent view mentioned in code is actually 50% opaque with bg color as white. Sorry if I was not clear.

Comment: And the red view portion is actually a camera?

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup Yes, that would be the preview layer of camera.